# Exponentially increase scrolling speed in a RecyclerView? (Wearable)

Tags: android, wear-os, android-recyclerview

**[Context: On a Wearable]**

Lets say you have a RecyclerView with 1000 items.

You want to go from item 50 to 500.

I want the user to scroll by each item as it usually works, but if he continues scrolling fast - I want the RecyclerView to start scrolling exponentially faster.

E.g.

At first it might scroll from item to item such as : `0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3` ...

As user scrolls longer and faster: `3 -> 6 -> 9 -> 12` ...

And this goes on and on: `12 -> 24 -> 36 -> 48` ...

**Is this possible? How do I do it? Many thanks.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I love it when there are simple solutions to what seems to be a complex problem. Simply override the fling method in your custom RecyclerView class (in my case the WearableListView - which in turn extends RecyclerView). This will increase/decrease the speed in which you scroll the list, and increasing this as the user scrolls will achieve the exact logic I was looking for! Hope it helps you too.

```
public class DynamicWearableListView extends WearableListView {

    //Constructors

    @Override
    public boolean fling(int velocityX, int velocityY) {
        velocityY *= mVelocityMultiplier;
        return super.fling(velocityX, velocityY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't I  find the fling method in the RecyclerView super class?